# filter record by current date on FIND_IN_SET() Function

Tags: mysql

im using Find Inset Function From Mysql to  get results.

```
SELECT 
    Finalpoint As Finalpoint,
    Ticket As Ticketnum, 
    Task_Details As TaskDetails, 
    AssignDate As AssinDate, 
    IF(
        FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Leader) OR FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner), 
        Leader, 
        NULL
    ) AS Leader1, 
    IF(
        FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner) OR FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner),
        Partner, 
        NULL
    ) AS Partner2 
FROM performance 
HAVING Leader1 IS NOT NULL OR Partner2 IS NOT NULL
```

above query is working fine. but i want filter specific date from that query. i have used 
`curdate()` function but my query is not gettinbg the result.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your post. and show us also what you added to ypur query

Comment: im using this code but my date is not filtering and it gives me 0 values `SELECT Finalpoint As Finalpoint,Ticket As Ticketnum, Task_Details As TaskDetails,  AssignDate = curdate() As AssinDate,


IF(FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Leader) OR FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner),
          Leader, NULL) AS Leader1 ,
       IF(FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner) OR FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner),
          Partner, NULL) AS Partner2 
          
          
FROM performance
HAVING Leader1 IS NOT NULL OR Partner2 IS NOT NULL`

Comment: You have to add before the HAVING a Where AssignDate = curdate()    or use HAVING (Leader1 IS NOT NULL OR Partner2 IS NOT NULL) AND AssignDate = curdate()

Comment: '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as AssD = curdate() assigntable' at line 1'

Comment: See please my answer and copy one of these(Your porblem,is  **AssignDate = curdate() As AssinDate** is no valid sql code. so take as mentioned my query please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have twi possibility

```
SELECT 
    Finalpoint As Finalpoint,
    Ticket As Ticketnum, 
    Task_Details As TaskDetails, 
    AssignDate As AssinDate, 
    IF(
        FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Leader) OR FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner), 
        Leader, 
        NULL
    ) AS Leader1, 
    IF(
        FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner) OR FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner),
        Partner, 
        NULL
    ) AS Partner2 
FROM performance 
Where AssignDate = curdate()
HAVING Leader1 IS NOT NULL OR Partner2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Or you add the date to your having. **Notice** the brackets around the other criteria

```
SELECT 
    Finalpoint As Finalpoint,
    Ticket As Ticketnum, 
    Task_Details As TaskDetails, 
    AssignDate As AssinDate, 
    IF(
        FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Leader) OR FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner), 
        Leader, 
        NULL
    ) AS Leader1, 
    IF(
        FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner) OR FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner),
        Partner, 
        NULL
    ) AS Partner2 
FROM performance 
HAVING (Leader1 IS NOT NULL OR Partner2 IS NOT NULL) AND AssignDate = curdate();
```

Without data i can not test if that gives any results.

Comment: SQL RETURN an empty result set ,
AssignDate field SQL Type is "datetime", default it was set to "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ",  `assigndate Current data is equal to name "fayaz" is 2019-12-04 22:20:54, 2019-12-06 01:07:21 . none of these dates results came with that query`

Comment: Change the Code to the following and it worked, Thankx alot ```SELECT Finalpoint As Finalpoint, Ticket As Ticketnum, Task_Details As TaskDetails, IF( FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Leader) OR FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner), Leader, NULL ) AS Leader1, IF( FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner) OR FIND_IN_SET('fayaz', Partner), Partner, NULL ) AS Partner2 FROM performance Where AssignDate = curdate() HAVING Leader1 IS NOT NULL OR Partner2 IS NOT NULL```